# Toolbar Menu Item spacing issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a toolbar in my Android app with a custom menu item as follows:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/todayIcon"
        android:title=""
        app:actionViewClass="com.anubavam.creatrix.modules.calendar.view.TodayMenuTextView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</group>
```

I am customizing the menu item using:

```
app:actionViewClass="com.anubavam.creatrix.modules.calendar.view.TodayMenuTextView
```

This is my `TodayMenuTextView` class:

```
public class TodayMenuTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    public TodayMenuTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TodayMenuTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TodayMenuTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_go_to_today));
        setMaxLines(1);
        setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});
        setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setTextSize(12);
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

This is my output:

[image]

My menu item is going to the right of the toolbar. Also the menu item click is not working.

How can I add menu item a the right margin and solve the click issue?

Comment: set padding all 0

Comment: text inside the TextView(ie. 2) going some what abouve when setting all padding to zero.

Comment: i dont see any problem in picture

Comment: you are just giving top padding instead of that use setPadding(10, 10, 10,10);

Answer (score 0):

set LayoutParams to menu item

```
  LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
   );
 params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
 yourImageBiew.setLayoutParams(params);
```